# TypeNotFound error in Suds Soap library

Tags: python, web-services, soap, wsdl, suds

I'm trying to call a SOAP service from the Dutch land register ([WSDL here](http://www1.kadaster.nl/1/schemas/kik-inzage/20141101/verzoekTotInformatie-2.1.wsdl)) with the [suds library](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/). I first introspect the SOAPservice as follows:

```
>>> from suds.client import Client
>>> client = Client(url='http://www1.kadaster.nl/1/schemas/kik-inzage/20141101/verzoekTotInformatie-2.1.wsdl')
>>> print client

Suds ( https://fedorahosted.org/suds/ )  version: 0.4 GA  build: R699-20100913

Service ( VerzoekTotInformatieService ) tns="http://www.kadaster.nl/schemas/kik-inzage/20141101"
   Prefixes (13)
      ns0 = "http://www.kadaster.nl/schemas/kik-inzage/20141101"
      ...
      ns9 = "http://www.kadaster.nl/schemas/kik-inzage/kadastraalberichtobject/v20141101"
   Ports (1):
      (VerzoekTotInformatieSOAP)
         Methods (1):
            VerzoekTotInformatie(ns3:Aanvraag Aanvraag, )  # <== WE WANT TO CALL THIS
         Types (278):
            ns10:AN1
            ns10:AN10
            ...
            ns3:Aanvraag  # <== FOR WHICH WE NEED THIS TYPE
            ns10:AlgemeenAfsluiting
            ns10:AlgemeenBegin
            ...
```

So I want to call the (only available) method `VerzoekTotInformatie` (which means "RequestForInformation") which takes an `Aanvraag` object ("Aanvraag" means "Request"). As you can see the `Aanvraag` type is in the list of Types. So I tried creating it as [suggested in the docs](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki/Documentation#ComplexArguments), using:

```
>>> Aanvraag = client.factory.create('Aanvraag')
No handlers could be found for logger "suds.resolver"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/suds/client.py", line 234, in create
    raise TypeNotFound(name)
TypeNotFound: Type not found: 'Aanvraag'
>>>
```

Does anybody know why the type is not found, even though it is clearly displayed in the list of types?

All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the prefix:

```
In [9]: Aanvraag = client.factory.create('ns3:Aanvraag')

In [10]: Aanvraag
Out[10]:
(Aanvraag){
   berichtversie =
      (VersieAanvraagbericht){
         value = None
      }
   klantReferentie = None
   productAanduiding = None
   Gebruiker =
      (Gebruiker){
         identificatie = None
      }
   Ingang = <empty>
 }
```